# How to resign Keyboard on scrolling in either direction up or down in swift?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiscrollview

Dismiss the keyboard when scroll down the scrollview. And do not hide for scroll up(like comments screen in Instagram app). How to differentiate scroll up side and scroll downside?

Answer (score 22):

You can set `scroll view's` properties like,

```
  scrollView.keyboardDismissMode = .onDrag
```

or

```
 scrollView.keyboardDismissMode = .interactive
```

(`.OnDrag` and `.Interactive` for swift 3 )

Or you can use scrollview's `delegate` methods to detect scroll and can hide keyboard from that delegate method's implementation.

Answer (score 1):

In this way you can check in which direction scrollview scrolled.

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
     if(scrollView.panGestureRecognizer.translationInView(scrollView.superview).y > 0)
     {
        print("up")
      }
    else
    {
        print("down")
        //here you can dismiss keyboard.
     } 
}
```

Try this code it may help you.

Comment: thank u it is working fine